# Connecting from Erlang code to H2 DB

Tags: java, database, erlang, h2

Is there any Erlang driver for H2?
Failed to find any leads.

Suggestion of how to run queries on H2 from Erlang code would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2 supports [the PostgreSQL network protocol](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#odbc_driver), possibly you could use a [Erlang PostgreSQL client](https://github.com/wg/epgsql).

I have never tried it however, and possibly there are some incompatibility problems. If you find any, please use the [H2 Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/h2-database).